# How to show that a set is an invariant set for my system?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, kalman-filter

I have this type of systems: $\;x(k+1) = -0.5x(k)$

and I have this set: $\;\big\{x\;|\;x^4\leqslant5\big\}\;.$

How can I show that this set is an invariant set ?
I would like to understand it mathematically.

So far I've tried what is written in blue in the picture, but I'm not sure it's done that way.

[image]

Comment: you should write your equations in $Mathjax$

Comment: thanks for the changes

Comment: @FerdinandoRosella, I cannot understand your question. Please, could you add more context and write what attempts you have done so far ? If you do not do it, moderators will close your post very soon and nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: till now i tried the attempts you can see in the picture, but i'm not sure it's right.

Comment: I just added a picture to better understand the problem

Comment: In the picture you can read the real problem if you come to a solution can you explain why? @Angelo

Comment: @FerdinandoRosella, what does $x^+$ mean ?

Comment: means x(k+1), in theory is the next state

Comment: this question has nothing to do with `invariant-theory`, `set-theory`, or `model-theory`. please read tag descriptions before using them in your question

Comment: I replaced the downvote by an upvoted now that the question is well written :-)

Comment: Your relation should be $x(k+1)=0.5x(k)$ instead of $x(k+1)=0.5x$.

Comment: yes thank you, well